# Using lapply on functions defined outside

Tags: r, data.table

This question is related to [R - pass fixed columns to lapply function in data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20230227/r-pass-fixed-columns-to-lapply-function-in-data-table) and [weighted means by group and column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145859/weighted-means-by-group-and-column), but somewhat different.

I would like to have one fixed column interacting with all other columns in a `data.table`. A trivial example to illustrate:

```
DT <- data.table(y = rnorm(10), x1 = rnorm(10), x2 = rnorm(10))
DT[, lapply(c('x1', 'x2'), function(x) get(x) * y)]
```

Now suppose that the operation is a lot more complicated than multiplication, such that I would like to define a standalone function outside the scope of the `data.table`:

```
fun <- function(x) {
    return(get(x) * y)
}
DT[, lapply(c('x1', 'x2'), fun)]
Error in get(x) : object 'x1' not found
```

Obvious there is an issue with variable scope, since the function defined outside the `data.table` cannot see the variables inside. Is there any clever trick to define the function outside `data.table` and still be able to use `lapply`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will wrap your self in knots if you are trying to combine references by character string and named variables. (and also by refering to "global" variables within functions)

The easiest way forward would be to define where `get` is looking for `x`, (and `y`)

Here is the function rewritten so that you can tell it where to look.

```
fun <- function(x,y,wherex=parent.frame(),wherey=parent.frame()) {
    return(get(x,wherex) * get(y,wherey))
}
```

`data.table` inspects the names present in `j`, and only loads in the required columns.

In your example, you don't use the column names, so nothing is available.

If you include `.SD` in the expression for `j`, it will load in all columns. You can use `.SD` as the `wherex`/`wherey` arguments to the newly defined `fun`

```
DT[, lapply(c('x1', 'x2'), fun, y = 'y' , wherex=.SD, wherey=.SD)]
 #              V1         V2
 #  1: -0.27871200  1.1943170
 #  2: -0.68843421 -1.5719016
 #  3:  1.06968681  2.8358612
 #  4:  0.21201412  1.0127712
 #  5:  0.05392450  0.2487873
 #  6:  0.04473767 -0.1644542
 #  7:  5.37851536  2.9710708
 #  8:  0.23653388  0.9506559
 #  9:  1.96364756 -1.4662968
 # 10: -0.02458077 -0.1197023
```

Note that you don't really need to wrap this in `[.data.table`

```
results <- setDT(lapply(c('x1','x2'), fun, y='y', wherex=DT,wherey=DT))
```

will return the same results.